# How to link my json data to html via knockout

Tags: jquery, html, json, knockout.js, oracle-jet

How do I link my JSON data to HTML, I have tried everything which I found on Stack Overflow but it didn't work?

JS:

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'ojs/ojselectcombobox', 'ojs/ojinputtext', 'ojs/ojdatetimepicker', 'ojs/ojinputtext'],
    function (oj, ko, $) {

        function CustomerViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            this.isRequired = ko.observable(true);
            self.formState = ko.observable('enabled');
            self.messages = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.placeholder = ko.observable(false);
            self.disableFormControls = ko.computed(function () {
                if (self.formState() == 'disabled')
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            });
            self.readonlyFormControls = ko.computed(function () {
                if (self.formState() == 'readonly')
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            });
            this.projectname = ko.observable();
            this.specification = ko.observable( );
            this.URS = ko.observable( );
            this.Design = ko.observable( );
            this.disableControls = ko.observable(false);
            this.val = ko.observableArray( );
            this.val1 = ko.observableArray( );
            this.val2 = ko.observableArray( );
            this.val3 = ko.observableArray( );
            this.val4 = ko.observableArray( );
            this.val5 = ko.observableArray( );
            var lgQuery = oj.ResponsiveUtils.getFrameworkQuery(oj.ResponsiveUtils.FRAMEWORK_QUERY_KEY.LG_UP);
            self.large = oj.ResponsiveKnockoutUtils.createMediaQueryObservable(lgQuery);


            self.onClick = function () {
                jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
                var data = {"Scenario": self.val(), "Complainces": self.val1(), "Role": self.val2(), "Size": self.val3(), "Duration": self.val4(), "Budget": self.val5()};
                $.getJSON("url",data).then(function(resData){
                    console.log(resData);
                });
                document.getElementById('secondStep').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('FirstStep').style.display = 'none';

            };
            self.onClick1 = function () {
                var dataVal2 = {"projectname": self.projectname(), "FunctionalSpecifications": self.specification(), "URS": self.URS(), "FunctionalDesign": self.Design(), "Scenario": self.val(), "Complainces": self.val1(), "Role": self.val2(), "Size": self.val3(), "Duration": self.val4(), "Budget": self.val5()};
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "url,
                    data: JSON.stringify(dataVal2),

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    processData: true,
                    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                        alert(data.result);
                        var projectId = data.result;
                        alert(projectId);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
                if (document.getElementById('secondStep')) {
                    if (document.getElementById('secondStep').style.display == 'none') {
                        document.getElementById('secondStep').style.display = 'block';
                        document.getElementById('thirdStep').style.display = 'none';
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('secondStep').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('thirdStep').style.display = 'block';
                    }
                }
            };
            self.returnWizard = function () {
                document.getElementById('secondStep').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('FirstStep').style.display = 'block';
            };
            self.returnWizard1 = function () {
                document.getElementById('thirdStep').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('secondStep').style.display = 'block';
            };

            self.handleActivated = function (info) {

            };
            handleAttached = function (info) {

            };
            self.handleBindingsApplied = function (info) {

            };
            self.handleDetached = function (info) {

            };
        }
        return new CustomerViewModel();
    }
);
```

the returned JSON looks like this

```
 Object {Scenario: "ScenaroioDoc1", Complainces: "ComplaincesDoc1", Role: "RoleDoc1", Size: "SizesDoc1", Duration: "DurationDoc1"}
```

and I had used data-bind with every possibilty it didn't work?

```
<div data-bind="text: resData.Scenario">
</div>
```

I've tried very different things but none are working, so if anybody has an idea on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you show us what your html looks like? is it the onclick method which returns the json? `$.getJSON("url",data).then(function(resData){
                    console.log(resData); // logic needed here?
                });`

Comment: yes on click it will call a service and the response is the above json

Comment: <a class="oj-button-primary oj-button" id="SButton" type="button" 
                                       data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojButton', 
                                 label: 'Get Documents',
                                 disabled: disableControls()},
                                 click: onClick"></a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JS:

```
self.Data = ko.observable();
self.onClick = function () {
    jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
    var data = {"Scenario": self.val(), "Complainces": self.val1(), "Role": self.val2(), "Size": self.val3(), "Duration": self.val4(), "Budget": self.val5()};
    $.getJSON("url",data).then(function(resData){
        document.getElementById('FirstStep').style.display = 'none';
        self.Data(resData);
        document.getElementById('secondStep').style.display = 'block';
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="secondStep" data-bind="with: Data">
    <div data-bind="text: Scenario"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: Complainces"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: Role"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: Size"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: Duration"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply tyler_mitchell it worked fine